# Connection to Amazon AWS highly unreliable

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, java, jdbc

I have a Java application that connects to MySQL on an Amazon EC2 (USA east region) instance with JDBC (using official latest Oracle drivers, location specified by IP). It also connects to S3 using Amazon's given SDK.

Problem is, while everything is fast and works great from any server, except for one server at a specific location (let's say LOC-A). Establishing connections in the application time out, or on average, are able to connect 1/10 restarts (but then are really slow). S3 connections error out at the same rate as well. MySQL Workbench hangs 9/10 times fetching results from the database.

The connection is a residential FIOS connection (hardwired from modem to PC). 50MB/s down, 25MB/s, <20ms ping. Computer and modem restarted. Firewall disabled. Latest network drivers. DNS, ARP caches cleared. All privileges for MySQL user for any hostname.

Like I said, any other server works great, this specific computer or network is terrible.

I understand I'm giving very high level information, but the code is stable and no changes were added.

Can anyone recommend next course of action, please? We are starting to suspect (tin-foil-hat-on) deep-packet inspection.

Comment: According to Amazon's health dashboard: "Network connectivity

We are observing an issue outside of our network that is preventing a small number of Verizon FiOS customers from reaching the US-EAST-1 Region. Connectivity within the Region as well as connectivity from other networks is not impacted." See http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Comment: I don't see that?

Comment: It's a big green box at the top of the page...

Comment: Oh, my. That is unbelievable. I never seen an error like that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because AWS are observing an issue outside of our network that is preventing a small number of Verizon FiOS customers from reaching the US-EAST-1 Region. Connectivity within the Region as well as connectivity from other networks is not impacted.

Comment: Why do you even close this when the question is solved? Just to keep up with the bureaucracy? "...minimal understanding of the problem being solved". Are you kidding me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next course of action is to check with your provider (in this case Amazon) to see if they know anything about the issue.

[It seems that they do:](http://status.aws.amazon.com/)

> ### Network connectivity
>
> We are observing an issue outside of our network that is preventing a small number of Verizon FiOS customers from reaching the US-EAST-1 Region. Connectivity within the Region as well as connectivity from other networks is not impacted.

Comment: Wow, that is quite something. I've seen degraded performance over the last few weeks and now it totally errors out. I've never seen that type of error either on AWS dashboard. Thanks guys!